# CSS linear-gradient with semi-transparent borders

Tags: html, css

I'm using linear-gradients with semi-transparent borders for creating modules and buttons etc. Using (for example) `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` as the border colour is convenient, because I can set any background colour on my elements without having to worry about the border colour again.

However I've noticed a very odd effect - when combined with a linear-gradient background, browsers use the height of the element's padding box to calculate the height of the gradient, which means it repeats over the top and bottom margins, creating a very odd effect: [image: Gradient/Borders example]

Here is the CSS that generates the "Actual" box:

```
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%); 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Now I've already found a workaround that allows me to achieve the desired effect, by forcing the `background-size` to be 100% + the border size. This is what generated the "Desired" box (.box2):

```
.box2 {
    background-position: 0 center;
    background-size: auto calc(100% + 50px);
}
```

However that seems a bit hacky.

**So my question is**: Can anyone explain why this is - I can't find it documented anywhere, and does anyone have a neater solution?

Here's the JS Fiddle that I used to create the examples, and it also includes a box with an actual image background for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/29rgksgx/4/

Comment: There is a detailed explanation of why this happens (and why the property mentioned in vals' answer fixes it) in my answer to the linked thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose which of the boxes is used as a reference for the background

Choose border-box and it will work as desired

You can choose between border content and padding box

```css
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);   
    background-origin: border-box;  /* the trick */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that does the trick! Thanks.